# Integrate Push Notifications for Android Firebase Application

Tags: android, mobile, push-notification, firebase, real-time

We are building a real time chat application for businesses to connect to their consumers. For now we are using Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/) as the backend for the prototype and it seems to be working fine. However we have run into a major roadblock in terms of push notifications. What is the best method to integrate push notifications in a chat application for each new message using Firebase as the backend?

I have read somewhere that you can set up a Heroku Node.JS server to listen for push notifications, however we are unable to find any specific steps to do so. Also, is this a viable solution in terms of cost and scalability? We envision millions of users on the platform at some stage.

Please let me know if there is any alternate solution that we can use.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually for push notifications people set up a queue in their Firebase database of the notifications to send. They then run a nodejs script that listens to `child_added` events on the queue and that interacts with APN and/or GCM to send the actual notification. For a good queue implementation, see https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-05-15-introducing-firebase-queue.html

Comment: Have a look at Realtime Code Hosting (http://storage-public.realtime.co/documentation/code-hosting-guide/1.0/overview.html). As Frank was mentioning in the previous comment you can run a mule (or several) to listen to your Firebase queue changes and send the Push Notifications. Or you could use Realtime Cloud Storage (AWS DynamoDB + real-time data sync) with integrated support for APNS /GCM topic based push notifications (using the same API and platform). More at http://framework.realtime.co/storage/